# Is it legal for Shutterfly to expire their Prepaid Plan in CA, USA

Tags: united-states, california, gift-card

Sorry if this is off topic, but thought it was the best site for this question:

I was just on Shutterfly and noticed that I had an expired [prepaid plan](http://shutterfly-2.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/317/kw/prepaid%20plan). I live in California and remember there are some consumer protections regarding [gift cards](http://www.dca.ca.gov/publications/legal_guides/s-11.shtml). Does anyone know if the Shutterfly's prepaid plan qualifies as a "gift card" and if so, whether it's legal for them to expire?

Comment: This is going to be state-specific and depend on exactly how the law, and the prepay contract, were written.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](http://sacramento.cbslocal.com/2015/04/22/call-kurtis-can-prepaid-cards-for-services-expire/) describing someone who bought a discount pass for an "indoor playground".  In the article, an attorney is quoted:

> “These play passes may not fall under the gift card law,” because Barlow says these VIP cards don’t come with a cash value, like gift cards do.
>
> “What the consumer is buying is the play pass itself,” he said.

Shutterfly has terms on [their website](http://shutterfly-2.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/320/kw/prepaid%20plan/related/1) saying:

> Please note: the plan itself has been purchased to buy the physical products at a discounted rate, but the physical products (prints, cards, calendars) have yet to be purchased.

This certainly sounds like an attempt to move the prepaid plan out of the gift-card category.  In other words, by putting money into the prepaid account, you have purchased the privilege of obtaining future services from Shutterfly at a discounted rate.

Of course, I'm not an attorney, so I'm just repeating secondhand (or actually thirdhand) information here.  You would probably have to consult a lawyer to find out if you could really sue Shutterfly under California law.